# 404 Error when logging in atlas layer

Tags: android, layer, atlas

I tried to run Atlas android sample with my layer Id but I am getting following error :

E/AtlasIdentityProvider﹕ Got status 404 [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found] when logging in. Request: https://layer-identity-provider.herokuapp.com/apps/xxx/atlas_identities login: Ee, nonce: xxx

I am sure my id is correct because it wotks with another sample without any exeption (https://github.com/layerhq/quick-start-android)

What is the problem? How Can I fix this?

Regards

Comment: As I am facing the same issue.
Did you get anything about the same ?

Comment: I'm a Partner Engineer at Layer. You can find the answer here:
https://support.layer.com/hc/en-us/articles/207719766-Why-is-the-Atlas-Messenger-project-throwing-a-404-error-when-I-try-to-authenticate-

Comment: Anybody made it work?